# How does ansible's unarchive module look for the tar binary?

Tags: linux, macos, module, ansible, tar

I'm trying to execute an ansible playbook that has a task utilizing the `unarchive` module. Because I'm doing this on OSX, I need it to use `gnu-tar`, instead of the `bsd tar` that typically comes with OSX, since [BSD tar is not officially supported](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/issues/3952#issuecomment-260207094).

I've installed `gnu-tar` using `brew`, and placed this package's `gnubin` folder ahead of other paths in the `$PATH` variable. However, my playbook still looks for `tar` in the `/usr/bin` folder (the location of the original `tar`), instead of the newly installed `gnu-tar`.

My question is, how does the `unarchive` module look for the `tar` binary, and what would be the best way for me to override this behavior so that it utilizes `gnu-tar`, instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution.

Before we proceed, this is my code for making sure that the brew-installed `gnu-tar` takes precedence over the `bsd-tar` that comes with OSX:

```
# gnu-tar
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/gnu-tar/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"
export MANPATH="/usr/local/opt/gnu-tar/libexec/gnuman:$MANPATH"
```

This code was originally located in my `~/.bash_profile` file.

The way that ansible looks up the `tar` binary is as you'd expect: the `$PATH` variable, like any other process. However, running a play creates an *interactive non-login shell*. As explained [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/51038), the `~/.bashrc` file gets loaded for *interactive non-login shells*, while `~/.bash_profile` gets loaded for *login shells*.

Since my code was located in the `~/.bash_profile` file, it never executes whenever I run a play. Again, this is because running a play creates an *interactive non-login shell* that *does not* load `~/.bash_profile`. Hence, the code should actually be in `~/.bashrc`.

True enough, the moment I moved my code to the `~/.bashrc` was when my task started using the installed `gnu-tar`. I was able to confirm this by creating a task to register `which tar` into a variable and printing it in another `debug` task.

Answer (score 0):

From the source code it looks like tar is looking for a `gtar` binary and if not a `tar`

```bash
# Prefer gtar (GNU tar) as it supports the compression options -zjJ
self.cmd_path = self.module.get_bin_path('gtar', None)
if not self.cmd_path:
    # Fallback to tar
    self.cmd_path = self.module.get_bin_path('tar')
```

Thus, aliasing your brew installed gnu tar as "gtar" or "tar" should fix the problem